# Iterate elements of array using pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, iterator

I try execute code:

```
char* m[3] = {"123", "456", "789"};
for(char* st=*m; st!=0; st=*(m+1))
{
    cout <<st;
}
```

but it hung up and print: `123456456456`...

Comment: Don't use a non-const `char *` to point to a nonmodifiable string literal.

Comment: `st=*(m+1)` - since second iteration you always point to second string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop you wrote is invalid

```
char* m[3]={"123","456","789"};
for(char* st=*m;st!=0; st=*(m+1))
{
    cout <<st;
}
```

Expression `*m` has type `char *` and array `m` does not contain NULL pointer. So condition `st!=0;`
is wrong. And the pointer always will point the same element because expression `st=*(m+1)` gives always the second element of the array

Also take into account that the correct definition of the array will be

```
const char* m[3] = { "123", "456", "789" };
```

because it is an array of pointers to string literals and string literals may not be changed.

You could use simply the range based for statement

```
const char* m[3] = { "123", "456", "789" };
for ( const char* st : m )
{
    cout <<st << std::endl;
}
```

Or you could use iterators in the loop. For example

```
const char* m[3] = { "123", "456", "789" };
for ( auto it = std::begin( m ); it != std::end( m ); ++it )
{
    cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

And you could use standard algorithm `std::copy`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//,,, 
const char* m[3] = { "123", "456", "789" };
std::copy( std::begin( m ), std::end( m ),
           std::ostream_iterator<const char *>( std::cout, "\n" ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Stop using `char*` for strings immediately and start using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). The same goes for C-style arrays: start using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). This will save you years of your life and unnecessary pain.

Just look at how beautiful this code is:

```
std::array<std::string, 3> m = {"123", "456", "789"};
for (auto& s : m) 
    std::cout << s;
```

and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0b0c844d55f8011)'s the live example.

Comment: +1 If the OP is mandated to use `char const* m[]`, the very least they should do is take advantage of the second part of this answer, namely language-based range enumerator, which *will* work with a fixed array (i.e. change the `m` to the OP's array with appropriate `const`-ness, and the code will still compile). [**See it live**](https://ideone.com/MSpWMh)

Answer (score 1):

Using the code you provided here is one way of doing it:

```
const char* m[3]={"123","456","789"};
const unsigned int element_count = sizeof(m) / sizeof(m[0]);
//not a nice to have sizeof here, but i used this to keep the code
// consistent with the code provided in the question

for( const char** st = m; st!= (m + element_count) ; st ++ )
{
    cout << *st;
}
```

As you can see to iterate trough an array of `char*` elements you need to use a pointer to `char*` and therefore the type is `char **` for the iteration variable `st`.

The code you has was an infinite loop because you assigned `st` with `*(m+1)` which is never equal to 0, in fact it's the second element every time.

However there are safer ways of using doing this, by using a `std::vector` for example:

```
std::vector<std::string> m = {"123", "456", "789"};
for (auto& st : m) 
    std::cout << st;
//or:
for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = m.begin(),e = m.end();i != e;i++)
    std::cout << *i;
//or:
for(std::size_t i = 0;i < m.size() ;i++)
    std::cout << m[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you point a pointer to the same location in each iteration:

```
char* m[ 3]={ "123","456","789"};
for( char* st = *m; st != 0; st = *( m + 1))
                               // ^^^^^^^^^  <- this doesn't change, 
                               //               st points to *(m+1)
{
    std::cout << st;
}
```

Also **you should not use a non-const** `char *` to point to a nonmodifiable string literal:

```
const char* m[ 3]={ "123","456","789"};
const unsigned int n = sizeof( m) / sizeof( m[ 0]);

for( const char** st = m; st != (m + n) ; st ++ )
{
    cout << *st;
}
```

Even range - based iteration will work:

```
const char* m[ 3] = { "123", "456", "789" };
for ( const char* st : m )
{
    std::cout << st << std::endl;
}
```

If for some reason you have to stick to simple iteration, this will also work:

```
const char* m[ 3]={ "123","456","789"};
const char* st;
int r = 0;
for( st = *m; r < 3; st = *( m+r))
{
    std::cout << st << std::endl;
    r++;
}
```

---

Please consider using a **standard** container, i.e `std::vector` or `std::array`. It will help you a lot, mainly in dynamic memory management.

```
std::vector< std::string> v = { "123", "456", "789"};
for ( auto& s : v) 
    std::cout << s;
```

Comment: why use `char**` instead of using just `char*` ?

Comment: because I want to iterate over array using pointer increment, st++ as a pointer will be correctly incremented to point to next element which is const char*, so pointer itself must be const char **

Comment: what's wrong with just using `char* st = m`, incrementing it and outputting `cout << st;` ? condition is `st!=m[n]` or `st!=*(m+n)`

Comment: this won't work, m decays to char**, note the declaration: char* m[3]

Comment: sorry, I meant `char* st = m[0]`. it's supposed to work, isn't it

Comment: no, it won't work because st will be incremented by a single character resulting in 123233(garbage here)

Comment: yes, you're right. `st++` would imply moving char size forward, rather than pointer to char size.

Comment: that's right, but I didn't really understand why you chose `st!=0` as a terminating condition :/

Comment: `st != *(m+3)` maybe :-)

Comment: this should be int r = 0;
for( st = *m; r < 3; st = *( m+r))

Answer (score 0):

This is the least intrusive solution:

```
char* m[4] = {"123", "456", "789", NULL};
for(char** st=m; *st!=0; st=(st+1))
{
    cout <<*st;
}
```